# Linq selectmany issue

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, where-clause

I have some trouble with this selection

```
var pAssets = sPallets.SelectMany(p => 
       AsyncHelper.RunSync(() => assetRepository.GetByPalletAsync(p.Id))).ToArray();
```

I have to add a where condition like `pAsset.isEnabled == true`.

So I tried

```
var pAssets = sPallets.SelectMany(p => 
    AsyncHelper.RunSync(() => _assetRepository.GetByPalletAsync(p.Id)))
    .where(p => isEnabled==true).ToArray();
```

and also

```
var pAssets = sPallets.SelectMany(p => 
    AsyncHelper.RunSync(() => _assetRepository.GetByPalletAsync(p.Id)))
   .where(p => p.isEnabled==true).ToArray();
```

But I get the following error:

> pAssets Does not contain a definition and no extension method was found

My pAsset Class is:

```
public class Pallet : Entity<string>
{
    public string PalletNumber { get; private set; }
    public string PalletStatusName { get; private set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? CloseDate { get; private set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public bool isEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is the return type of `_assetRepository.GetByPalletAsync(p.Id)` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 sPallets.Where(x=>x.isEnabled == true).SelectMany()
```

You need to use above code.

Comment: Probably just shorten it to `sPallets.Where(x=> x.isEnabled).SelectMany()`

Comment: @VijayRaheja Yes it will work, but the point he was making was there's no need to do IsEnabled == true. It is redundant.